# Node passed as a parent node in recursive call not updating

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public class LinkedList{
    private class Node{
        int value;
        Node next;
    }
    private Node root;
    public LinkedList(){
        root = null;
    }
    public void insert(int value){
        root = insert(root, root, value);
    }
    public Node insert(Node node, Node parent, int value){
        if(root == null){
            node = new Node();
            node.value = value;
        }else if(node == null){
            node = new Node();
            node.value = value;
            parent.next = null;
        }else{
            node.next = insert(node.next, node, value);
        }
        return node;
    }
    public void printAll(){
        printAll(root);
    }
    public void printAll(Node node){
        Node traverse = node;
        while(traverse != null){
            System.out.println("This node's value is " + traverse.value);
            traverse = traverse.next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        myList.insert(5);
        myList.insert(2);
        myList.printAll();
    }
}
```

Here is a program explaining my troubles. I have an insert function that has both the current node and the parent node as parameters. For the first insertion, I insert 5 into the list, the root basically becomes the Node with 5. For the second insertion, I insert 2 into the list, but this time it is supposed to set its parent node's next to null.

When I print after both insertions, it should display

```
This node's value is 5
```

But instead, it still shows that the parent's next is still link to the 2nd node.

```
This node's value is 5
This node's value is 2
```

Why doesn't my parent.next = null take effect? Is there a way to fix this? I have an implementation that requires the ability to modify the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing null,null when inserting the first node. Then, which node public `Node insert(Node node, Node parent, int value)` will return. Take a look again

```
public void insert(int value){
        root = insert(root, root, value);
    }
```

Comment: I see! I modify the parent in the next recursive call but as soon as I'm done with that call, the node is returned without modification to the root